# Issues running yourkit in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, yourkit

[image]I want to Profile springboot application using yourkit. But i am unable to profile. Getting below issue .

I have installed yourkit plugin in eclipse and able to see the yourkit profiler icon to profile application.

When i ran profile as java application i am getting above error prompting window.

No valid yourkit java profiler plugin configuration settings are found :
file c:\users.yjp\ide2014.txt is missing or is obsolet

To solve the problem:
1)Launch  yourkit java profiler
2)Run "Tools|Integrate with IDE"

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done what the message suggests? Do you run Eclipse and YourKit under the same Linux user?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the version of your YourKit java plugin on Eclipse is consistent to the YourKit Java Profiler (This is very important!).
2. Open YourKit UI (from YourKit-Directory/bin/profiler.sh).
3. Run YourKit Profile again on Eclipse. They should connect automatically.